# My android app takes very much memory and stops responding

Tags: java, android, xml

**Please Share code in answers if possible**
Here is My code, basically I think my app is not responding after sometime maybe because the freezing gui and high memory usage, It is using even 16.8 MB of memory while in background. Please share some tips by which I can make my app simple and fast without losing functionality.

## StopWatch.java

```java
package com.study.meter;

import android.app.Service;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Handler;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.Context;

public class StopWatch extends Service{
    public static StopWatch getStopWatch;
    public static int StopWatchSecs;
    public static boolean isStopWatchRunning = false;
    public static boolean isRunning;
    public String StopWatchTime;

    private NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    private Intent notificationIntent;
    private PendingIntent contentIntent;
    private Notification notificaton;
    private NotificationManager manager;
    private String StopWatchNotificationText,StopWatchNotificationTitle;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        return START_CONTINUATION_MASK;

    }
    
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        getStopWatch = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        isRunning = false;
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Destroyed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        super.onStart(intent,startid);
        isRunning = true;

    }

    public Handler StopWatchHandler = new Handler();
    public Runnable StopWatchRunnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            StopWatchSecs++;
            
            int seconds = StopWatchSecs;
            int hours = seconds / 3600;
            int minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
            int secs = seconds % 60;

            // Format the seconds into hours, minutes,
            // and seconds.
            StopWatchTime
                = String
                      .format(Locale.getDefault(),
                              "%d:%02d:%02d", hours,
                              minutes, secs);

            // if app is running then change counting
            if(MainActivity.Stop_Watch!=null && MainActivity.isAppRunning)
            {
                // Set the text view text.
                MainActivity.Stop_Watch.setText(StopWatchTime);
            }
            addStopWatchNotification("StopWatch",StopWatchTime);
            StopWatchHandler.postDelayed(StopWatchRunnable,1000);
        }
    };

    public void Start_Watch()
    {
        StopWatchHandler.post(StopWatchRunnable);
    }
    public void Stop_Watch()
    {
        StopWatchHandler.removeCallbacks(StopWatchRunnable);
    }
    public String Start_Or_Stop_Watch()
    {
        String result = "Start";
        if(isStopWatchRunning)
        {
            result = "Resume";
            isStopWatchRunning = false;
            Stop_Watch();
        }
        else if(!isStopWatchRunning)
        {
            result = "Pause";
            isStopWatchRunning = true;
            Start_Watch();
        }
        return result;
    }

    // adding new Handler for notifications to not overload memory
    public Handler StopWatchNotificationHandler = new Handler();
    public Runnable StopWatchNotificationRunnable;


   public void addStopWatchNotification(String title,String text)
   {
    if(builder==null)
    {
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify_icon)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
    }
    if(notificationIntent==null)
    {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    }
    if(contentIntent==null)
    {
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    }
   

    if(manager==null)
    {
        manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);   
    }
    if(StopWatchNotificationRunnable==null)
    {
        StopWatchNotificationRunnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                builder
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text);

                notificaton = builder.build();
                notificaton.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
                manager.notify(0, notificaton);
            }
        };
    }
    StopWatchNotificationText = text;
    StopWatchNotificationTitle = title;
    StopWatchNotificationHandler.post(StopWatchNotificationRunnable);
    }
}
```

## MainActivity.java

```java
package com.study.meter;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public static boolean isAppRunning;
    public static TextView Stop_Watch;
    public static MainActivity activity;
    public Button Start_Watch;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        // set content view
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // hide statusbar
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        activity = this;
        
        // set the value of StopWatch
        Stop_Watch = findViewById(R.id.StopWatch);
        Start_Watch = findViewById(R.id.StartWatch);

        //if StopWatch service is not running 
        if(!StopWatch.isRunning)
        {
            // start the service
            startService(new Intent(this, StopWatch.class));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        isAppRunning = true;

        if(StopWatch.StopWatchSecs!=0)
        {
            // if stopwatchsecs is not equal to null or 0
            if(StopWatch.isStopWatchRunning)
            {
                // if stopwatch is running in background
                Start_Watch.setText("Pause");
            }else
            {
                // if stopwatch is not running in background
                Start_Watch.setText("Resume");
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        isAppRunning = false;
        super.onPause();
    }

    // "StartWatch" click
    public void StartorStop(View v)
    {
        Button sv = (Button)v;
        String StartWatchText = StopWatch.getStopWatch.Start_Or_Stop_Watch();
        sv.setText(StartWatchText);
    }
}
```

## AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.study.meter"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.StudyMeter">
        <service
            android:name=".StopWatch"
            android:stopWithTask="false"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

## activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/StopWatch"
        android:textSize="65dp"
        android:text="0:00:00"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/StartWatch"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/StartWatch"
        android:text="Start"
        android:onClick="StartorStop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/StopWatch"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an architecture problem, try to modulate more your Java code by dividing it in more activities, too much tasks in few activities causes crashes and poor performance ;)